# Constant-speed, straight-line spacetime trajectories and light

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime

If orbiting objects are actually following constant speed, straight line paths in spacetime, why is it that massless particles (light) do not follow these paths?

Comment: Light also follows geodesics, just light-like instead of time-like ones.

Answer (score 1):

As ACuriousMind stated in his comment, light also follows geodesics. For a Lorentz-metric, such as the metric of spacetime in GR, $g_{ab}$, a tangent vector $X^a$ is *spacelike* if $g_{ab}X^aX^b>0$, *timelike*, if $g_{ab}X^aX^b<0$ and *lightlike* or *null*, if $g_{ab}X^aX^b=0$ (assuming $(-+++)$ signature, if opposite signature is used, then these signs are reversed).

A geodesic $\gamma:(a,b)\rightarrow M$ is spacelike/timelike/null if its tangent vector field is everywhere spacelike/timelike/null.

In GR, the worldlines of massive particles are timelike, and the worldlines of massless particles (eg. photons) is null.

You don't observe photons orbiting anything, since that would require extreme circumstances. However, as far as I recall, the event horizon of black holes, when stretched out in time into a "world tube" are null hypersurfaces, eg. light can actually orbit black holes.

Comment: Very cool, thank you. I'm going to have to read about this a bit more before I really grasp all of that, but I'm starting to get the idea.